# How to access to SalesForce users profiles using Web Service API?

Tags: web-services, salesforce

Is it possible to read list of users or user profiles from SalesForce WebService?
I can't find any method which allows to touch user collection from partner or enterprise web service API. 
binding.getUserInfo() allows me retrieving current user only. But what about all users? My account allows me managing users and I can see them from web user interface. Now I need to read user names, etc. from web service API.

Answer (score 1):

You would use a soql query on the User and/or Profile objects, e.g. `select id,username from User`

Comment: sure, depends what exact fields you want. if this answer helped, please go ahead and accept it.